# Modeling empirical probability densities

Tags: modeling, nonparametric, density-function

Say we have a classic regression problem in which we have a numeric outcome along with some predictors, both numeric and categorical. In a typical prediction problem we use to estimate some parameter like the mean of the outcome , but what if we want to estimate the "statistically different" densities based on that predictors?

I know two possible ways of doing this, first would be a Bayesian approach, and other could be some parametric model like AFT in survival analysis where we estimate the parameters of a family of distributions (logistic, lognormal etc.) restricted in some kind of problems where like that where the formulation allow it.

The question is weather exists some general approximation to estimate that in a nonparametrical way (suppose we have two-modal or some other no theoretical distributions)and if it could be a non-bayesian approach or we necessarily have to take a Bayesian approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, this really isn't possible. No finite sample can tell you whether there are narrow spikes in the density function, and there is no unbiased estimator for pdf.

However, you can do something similar, which may meet the goal: you can estimate the Cumulative Density Function. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov theorem says that the empirical CDF is a good estimator of the true CDF.